# Laravel - compact() IDE (PHPStorm) marks variable as not used

Tags: laravel

Laravel - when I use compact() to send array of variables to view, my IDE (PHPStorm) doesn't see that variable is used and marks it as not used
What to do to mark it used in this case ?
I think that it would be better if compact was getting variable as a parameter, but not it's name as string

```
public function myControllerAction($param1, $param2)
    {
        $param3 = 'value';

        return view('mycomponent.myview', compact([
            'param1',
            'param2',
            'param3'
        ]));
    }
```

if I remove array symbols, it works! but I see it now like this:
[image: http://joxi.ru/bmoBLJxFxDLDVr.jpg]

and it is not very readable

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Are you using Laravel Plugin? Did you activate it?

Comment: I've edited question, added a code example and that it is right when I send an array of variables

Comment: You have used array in compact compact `([
            'param1',
            'param2',
            'param3'
        ])` So just write `compact('param1','param2','param3')`

Comment: you can turn the hints off altogether, by navigating to Editor | General | Appearance and deselecting Show parameter name hints.

Comment: What will be right template for exception for hints for view ? I tried compact(*), view(*), and combinations, doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove that array symbol, compact will handle `single variable`, `array`, even `multidimensional array`

```
 public function myControllerAction($param1, $param2)
        {
            $param3 = 'value';

            return view('mycomponent.myview', compact('param1','param2','param3'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function myControllerAction($param1, $param2)
{
    $param3 = 'value';

    return view('mycomponent.myview', compact('param1','param2','param3'));


    OR


    return view('mycomponent.myview', ['param1'=>$param1,'param2'=>$param2,'param3'=>$param3]);
}
```